# What does the Na mean in Nahuatl

Tags: etymology, nahuatl

Wondering what the etymology of this word is, can't find it anywhere. I am looking for the full etymology of the word Nahuatl, but specifically just the Na part.

Comment: What makes you think the *na-* is a morpheme in and of itself? I'm not an expert on Nahuatl, but the root _nahua-_ means "to speak clearly/aloud". I'm not sure it can be broken down any farther than that.

Comment: It's not a separate morpheme, as far as I know. Nahuatl inflection is suffixal.

Comment: Here is something that raises a similar question about English: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbBITrZa6Ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Nothing, probably.

The verb *nahua-* means "to speak clearly/out loud", and I haven't seen any evidence for it being composed of multiple morphemes, or for **na-* having a meaning of its own.

(I've put in a request for Miller's *Uto-Aztecan Cognate Sets* at the library, which might give more conclusive proof, but it won't be in for a few days.)

Comment: Didn't even cross my mind to look for that as the base. Thank you for clarifying.